# MacVim + Mountain lion, added font spacing

Tags: macvim, osx-mountain-lion

Since upgrading to Mountain Lion, my MacVim has added some spacing to my font. I am using Monaco:h12 both in MacVim and in the Terminal.

I have created an image displaying the difference, and I have no clue why the font is displayed like this.

[image]

Large version:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/404783/macvim-vim.png

Any ideas?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing and have not yet found a way to correct.  As far as this question being closed as "off topic", the FAQ says questions may cover "software tools commonly used by programmers", and StackOverflow is home to MANY MacVim questions, including those regarding setting and adjusting fonts. Perhaps those who voted to close this can recommend a different StackExchange site to ask the question on so those of use (probably thousands or millions soon) experiencing this can find an answer?

Comment: Bug info and temporary work-around at http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=417 (from original poster).

Comment: TL;DR: enable experimental renderer in Preferences > Advanced. Thank you, Mike Fischer. Yet another helpful answer in a question StackOverflow closes.